# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Tags: java, android, encryption, keystore

I am developing an android application where I am trying to use the secretkeyfactory to set and get a secret value in a Keystore file. I am able to set the value but when I try to get the value it shows the following Error - java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:

**FUNCTION TO CREATE THE KEYSTORE FILE**

```
private static KeyStore createKeyStore(String fileName, String pw) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException {
    File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + filename);

    final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    if (file.exists()) {
      keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(file), pw.toCharArray());
    } else {
      keyStore.load(null, null);
      keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + filename), pw.toCharArray());
    }

    return keyStore;
  }
```

**FUNCTION TO GET THE VALUE**

```
public static String getKey(String key, String keystoreLocation, String keyStorePassword) throws Exception{
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    ks.load(null, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(keystoreLocation);
    ks.load(fIn, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEwithHmacSHA1");
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske =
      (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)ks.getEntry(key, keyStorePP);

    PBEKeySpec keySpec = (PBEKeySpec)factory.getKeySpec(
        ske.getSecretKey(),
        PBEKeySpec.class);

    char[] password = keySpec.getPassword();

    return new String(password);

  }
```

**FUNCTION TO SET THE VALUE**

```
public static void setKey(String key, String value, String keyStoreLocation, String keyStorePassword) throws Exception {

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEwithHmacSHA1");
    SecretKey generatedSecret = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(value.toCharArray()));

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    ks.load(null, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    ks.setEntry(key, new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry( generatedSecret), keyStorePP);

    FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(keyStoreLocation);
    ks.store(fos, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
  }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseSecretKeyFactory.engineGetKeySpec(BaseSecretKeyFactory.java:73)
```

**ERROR occurs in this line in the getKey function**

```
PBEKeySpec keySpec = (PBEKeySpec)factory.getKeySpec(
            ske.getSecretKey(),
            PBEKeySpec.class);
```

Comment: The password of a key is not a key.

Answer (score 0):

(1)It's ok but it doesn't work：

```
SecretKey key = ske.getSecretKey();
SecretKeySpeckeySpec = (SecretKeySpec)factory.getKeySpec(ke.getSecretKey(),SecretKeySpec.class);
```

(2)code is ok but will get a error：
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec cannot be cast to javax.crypto.interfaces.PBEKey

```
PBEKey key = (PBEKey)ske.getSecretKey();
PBEKeySpec keySpec = (PBEKeySpec)factory.getKeySpec((PBEKey)ke.getSecretKey(),PBEKeySpec.class);
```

caused by:

```
public class SecretKeySpec implements KeySpec, SecretKey
public class PBEKeySpec implements KeySpec
```

ske.getSecretKey() just is one instance of SecretKeySpec

Solution:(Someone else's code)

```
void implInit(int opmode, Key key, AlgorithmParameterSpec params, SecureRandom random) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    char[] passwdChars = null;
    salt = null;
    iCount = 0;
    if (key instanceof javax.crypto.interfaces.PBEKey) {
        javax.crypto.interfaces.PBEKey pbeKey = (javax.crypto.interfaces.PBEKey) key;
        passwdChars = pbeKey.getPassword();
        // maybe null if unspecified
        salt = pbeKey.getSalt();
        // maybe 0 if unspecified
        iCount = pbeKey.getIterationCount();
    } else if (key instanceof SecretKey) {
        byte[] passwdBytes = key.getEncoded();
        if ((passwdBytes == null) || !(key.getAlgorithm().regionMatches(true, 0, "PBE", 0, 3))) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("Missing password");
        }
        passwdChars = new char[passwdBytes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < passwdChars.length; i++) {
            passwdChars[i] = (char) (passwdBytes[i] & 0x7f);
        }
    } else {
        throw new InvalidKeyException("SecretKey of PBE type required");
    }
    if (((opmode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) || (opmode == Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE)) && ((params == null) && ((salt == null) || (iCount == 0)))) {
        throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("Parameters missing");
    }
    if (params == null) {
        // generate default for salt and iteration count if necessary
        if (salt == null) {
            salt = new byte[DEFAULT_SALT_LENGTH];
            if (random != null) {
                random.nextBytes(salt);
            } else {
                SunJCE.RANDOM.nextBytes(salt);
            }
        }
        if (iCount == 0)
            iCount = DEFAULT_COUNT;
    } else if (!(params instanceof PBEParameterSpec)) {
        throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("PBEParameterSpec type required");
    } else {
        PBEParameterSpec pbeParams = (PBEParameterSpec) params;
        // make sure the parameter values are consistent
        if (salt != null) {
            if (!Arrays.equals(salt, pbeParams.getSalt())) {
                throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("Inconsistent value of salt between key and params");
            }
        } else {
            salt = pbeParams.getSalt();
        }
        if (iCount != 0) {
            if (iCount != pbeParams.getIterationCount()) {
                throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("Different iteration count between key and params");
            }
        } else {
            iCount = pbeParams.getIterationCount();
        }
    }
    // and openssl does.
    if (salt.length < 8) {
        throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("Salt must be at least 8 bytes long");
    }
    if (iCount <= 0) {
        throw new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("IterationCount must be a positive number");
    }
    byte[] derivedKey = derive(passwdChars, salt, iCount, keySize, CIPHER_KEY);
    SecretKey cipherKey = new SecretKeySpec(derivedKey, algo);
    byte[] derivedIv = derive(passwdChars, salt, iCount, 8, CIPHER_IV);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(derivedIv, 0, 8);
    // initialize the underlying cipher
    cipher.init(opmode, cipherKey, ivSpec, random);
}
```